# getServerSideProps doesn't show in inspect element

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using `getServerSideProps` function to render my components and scripts.

for example:

```
import Head from "next/head";

 <Head>
  return (
<Schema url={"/faq"}/>
)
 </Head>
```

`Schema` component is a script file for seo.
content of `schema` shows inside `view page source` but it doesn't show in `inspect element`.